# Why is AutoTest freezing on "loading autotest/rails_rspec2" for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, autotest

Whenever I run autotest on a Rails 3 app (no custom tests yet) it hangs at `loading autotest/rails_rspec2` and I'm still extremely new to Rails to know what to check/look for. 
 I've included my gemfile incase there is a known compatibility issue. Please let me know if you need anything else, thanks!

**Edit**
I am running on Ubuntu 10.10 in case it matters.

```
$ autotest
loading autotest/rails_rspec2
```

**GemFile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem "haml"
gem "formtastic"
gem "will_paginate"
gem "devise"
gem "omniauth"
gem "cancan"
gem "delayed_job"
gem "whenever"
gem "memcache-client"
gem "capistrano"
gem "mail"
gem "haml-rails"
gem "compass"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "rack-mount"

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec"
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.5.0"
  gem "autotest-standalone"
  gem "autotest-rails"
end

group :testing do
  gem "mocha"
  gem "shoulda"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
end

group :development do
  gem "cheat"
  gem "bullet"
  gem "ruby-growl"

end
```

**Gem Versions**

```
aaronh-chronic (0.3.9)
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.5)
actionpack (3.0.5)
activemodel (3.0.5)
activerecord (3.0.5)
activeresource (3.0.5)
activesupport (3.0.5)
addressable (2.2.4)
arel (2.0.9)
autotest (4.4.6)
autotest-notification (2.3.1)
autotest-rails (4.1.0)
autotest-standalone (4.5.5)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
builder (2.1.2)
bullet (2.0.1)
bundler (1.0.11)
cancan (1.6.4, 1.6.3)
capistrano (2.5.20)
cheat (1.3.0)
compass (0.10.6)
daemons (1.1.0)
delayed_job (2.1.4)
devise (1.2.1)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
factory_girl (1.3.3)
factory_girl_rails (1.0.1)
faraday (0.5.7)
formtastic (1.2.3)
haml (3.0.25)
haml-rails (0.3.4)
highline (1.6.1)
i18n (0.5.0)
jquery-rails (0.2.7)
mail (2.2.15)
memcache-client (1.8.5)
meta_where (1.0.4)
mime-types (1.16)
mocha (0.9.12)
multi_json (0.0.5)
multipart-post (1.1.0)
mysql2 (0.2.7)
net-ldap (0.1.1)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.3)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1)
nokogiri (1.4.4)
oa-basic (0.2.0)
oa-core (0.2.0)
oa-enterprise (0.2.0)
oa-more (0.2.0)
oa-oauth (0.2.0)
oa-openid (0.2.0)
oauth (0.4.4)
oauth2 (0.1.1)
omniauth (0.2.0)
orm_adapter (0.0.4)
paperclip (2.3.8)
polyglot (0.3.1)
pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.2)
rack (1.2.2)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-openid (1.2.0)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.5)
railties (3.0.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rest-client (1.6.1)
rspec (2.5.0)
rspec-core (2.5.1)
rspec-expectations (2.5.0)
rspec-mocks (2.5.0)
rspec-rails (2.5.0)
ruby-growl (3.0)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
rubyntlm (0.1.1)
shoulda (2.11.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.26, 0.3.25)
uniform_notifier (1.0.1)
warden (1.0.3)
whenever (0.6.7)
will_paginate (2.3.15)
ZenTest (4.5.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely not hanging, but rather not finding anything to test. This is likely due to [this post](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/03/15/rspec-2-and-autotest/) concerning changes to Rspec.

See that blog post for the long term solution. The simple quick-fix is to do:

`autotest -s rspec2`

Comment: I ended up buying a mac, adding rspec tests to the project, and so on before verifying this solution but judging by that post, I'm guessing this was likely it. Thanks a ton man.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is old but I have had this problem, so to anyone who's this issue. I didn't install the gem "rspec-autotest", you can fix it by adding this in your project's Gemfile

```
gem 'rspec-autotest'
```

Or simply typing

```
gem install rspec-autotest
```

You can find the project [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-autotest)